# File_picker / Image_picker crashes on Flutter web from mobile

Tags: flutter, mobile, crash, imagepicker, filepicker

I have a flutter web application in which I am trying to integrate a photo taking functionality. I tried the file_picker package, but for some reason the application sometimes crashes. It seems to be a device-related memory issue. I tested on Iphone SE and Samsung S21. Here is the code that allows me to collect images:

```
pickImage(Question question, context) async {
  try {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform
        .pickFiles(type: FileType.image, allowMultiple: true, allowCompression: true);
    if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < result.files.length; i++) {
        PlatformFile file = result.files[i];
        Uint8List? imageBytes = file.bytes!;
        Uint8List? compressedImage = await compressImage(imageBytes);
        question.addImage(
            'IMG_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}'); 
        question.addImageData(compressedImage);
        imageBytes = null; compressedImage = null;
      }
      result = null;
    }
  } catch(e) {
    print('ImagePicker failed : $e');
  }
}

Future<Uint8List> compressImage(Uint8List imageBytes) async {
  final List<int> compressedBytes = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
    imageBytes,
    quality: 10,
  );
  return Uint8List.fromList(compressedBytes);
}
```

In the previous code, I try to free the memory by setting my variables to null, but the problem persists, and I don't understand why. Should i use another package ??

**Edit**
I've just tried another package, image_picker, and it's all the same when i use my PWA from my mobile. After a few images picked, no error message, but the app crashes and reload...

```
final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    try {
      final XFile? pickedFile =
          await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        final imageBytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
        final base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
        setState(() {
          imgList.add(base64Image);
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(e.toString()),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: can you make sure about `file.bytes` is having data

Comment: I am sure about file.bytes, as i store the "compressedImage" into database, and retrieve the images later in my app. Actually, this code works. But it sometimes crashes when the mobile memory seems to be full

Comment: Can you update the question with the errors?

Comment: I've just edited my post. But actually there's no error message as i'm using this app from my mobile. I take a few pictures, it works and displays my images, and then i try to take another and it crashes :(

Comment: Back on my image picker functionnality, and i still have the crash issue.. :(